# Change font size based on container height/width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do simple jquery function:

```
<div id="container"><span>This is my text</span></div>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
});
```

css code:

```
* {
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
}

#container {
    height:100px;
    width:98%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
}
```

It works when I change resize window and refresh it, but I'd like it to work continously, so when I resize browser window font-size is changing dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/8TrTU/1627/

Comment: use $(window).resize() funtion

Comment: Won't it be easier to just use rem instead of px in your css?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a handler on the window resize event and execute a new function `update_fontsize` which holds your fontsize magic:

```
var update_fontsize = function(){
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
};

$(window).resize(function() {
    update_fontsize();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    update_fontsize();
});
```

Comment: Works a treat if you need a quick and lightweight implementation without the need for a full-blown plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code in a named `function` say - `changeSize` and call it in `document.ready` and `window.resize` as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8TrTU/1628/)**

```
function changeSize(){
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);   
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    changeSize();
    $(window).resize(changeSize);
});
```

or just once in `document.ready()` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(changeSize).trigger('resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.resize](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) function of jQuery

```js
var resizeFunction = function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   resizeFunction(); 
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
    resizeFunction();
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
}

#container {
    height:100px;
    width:98%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><span>This is my text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function(){
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
    });
  var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
    
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
}

#container {
    height:100px;
    width:98%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><span>This is my text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(window).resize` event:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
});
```

```css
* {
    font-family:Myriad Pro;
}

#container {
    height:100px;
    width:98%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"><span>This is my text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resizeFont() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($("#container").width()/4)+"px";
    $("#container span").css('font-size', fontSize);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    resizeFont();
});
$( window ).resize(function() {
    resizeFont();
});
```

Try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Since events on-resize result in a heavy overhead on webpage, i would recommend using `+value instead of parseInt()` in this case and `caching the DOM elements` not to select them again and again like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TrTU/1631/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using plain CSS, Take a look at this article:

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

Also, look into using em or rem as font-sizes vs. px.

https://j.eremy.net/confused-about-rem-and-em/